# I am getting Array out of bounds Exception but i don't know why the error is occurring

Tags: java, arrays

I want to store a string to a two dimensional array and print the array but iam getting the array index out of bound exception but i don't know what gets wrong here can someone help me to find what goes wrong in my code.

This is the code i had tried,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        String str=sc.next();
        char arr[][]=new char[5][5];
        char a[]=str.toCharArray();
        int l=a.length;
        int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                arr[i][j]=a[k];// this is the place where the error is occurred.
                k++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
The error iam getting is,
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24
    at try2.Try2.main(Try2.java:27)
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you're entering a string with length >= 25 ?

Comment: yes i am entering a string less then 25, but i need to print the value in a 5x5 array format, could you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if k exceeds lenght of given input then don't add character into your array and break the loop, check the below code,

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    String str=sc.next();
    char arr[][]=new char[5][5];
    char a[]=str.toCharArray();
    int l=a.length;
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            if(k != l) {
              arr[i][j]=a[k];// this is the place where the error is occurred.
              k++;
            }else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: if we do this then the same value will be printed again and again in the array. for example if the string is "welcome", then the output will be "w e l c o" will be printed five times in the new line but i need output to be printed as "w e l c o \n m e". I used \n to indicate that m and e should be printed in the new line.

Comment: hope that i had explained clearly, thanks in advance.!

Comment: Yes, your code really helped me. Thanks a lot,@MOnkey.

Comment: @Cheeku, could you please accept  my answer by clicked on the tick

Comment: Sure bro,@MOnkey.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of your `k++`

The inner loop runs 5 times, while the outer loop runs 5 times. Which makes the k++ execution to run 25 times. That is why you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException on a[k].

You should consider initializing your k value inside the first loop and outside the second loop. That would reset the value of `k` everytime the inner loops completes its iteration.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the data which is not available that is why you are getting the error.
You are running the loop 25 times.
To avoid that exception `char a[25]=str.toCharArray()`
Instead `char a[]=str.toCharArray()`

Hope this help.
If you like please up vote.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you bro..!!, I tried to up vote your answer but i have less than 15 reputation so it didn't get registered.

Comment: Thank you.Is the answer helped you?

Comment: It shows a warning message bro, I think that we can't declare like that, If i am wrong forgive me. As i was a beginner.@Pravin Ghorle

Comment: What is the warning message please let me know, so I can better understand.